# The actual proof of $\delta W = P dV$

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, pressure, volume

All "proofs" of $\,\delta W = P dV\,$ that I saw involve some piston and a gas cylinder. But how to prove this is true in general, that whenever (or maybe under some necessary conditions) we apply the first law of thermodynamics, we can substitute $PdV$ for $\delta W$.

***Edit:*** I would also like to remind that $\,\delta W = P dV\,$ holds for *reversible* processes only. So the answer must use this assumption. P is the pressure of a gas.

Comment: What is $P$ in the formula you would like to prove?

Comment: Pressure, everything I used is according to common notation

Comment: However, to answer correctly to your question, it makes an important difference if it is external or internal pressure.

Comment: From your edit, I would guess you are referring to the internal pressure, but it would be better to make it explicit.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Thermodynamics and Classical Mechanics are separate theories. As seen in Steeven's answer, you need both to prove your statement. This means that your statement is unprovable in Thermodynamics. You must add an additional postulate that specifies the relation between Thermodynamic & Mechanic W, P, U. Unfortunately this is never done in textbooks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a general material volume $V$, you can write the power of surface force acting on its contour $\partial V$ can be written as

$\dot{W} = \displaystyle \oint_{\partial V} \mathbf{t}_n \cdot \mathbf{u}$.

For a fluid with negligible viscous stress (either negligible viscosity or quasi-static conditions, as those often considered in thermodynamics), $\mathbf{t}_n = - P \mathbf{\hat{n}}$, so that

$\dot{W} = - \displaystyle \oint_{\partial V} P \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbf{u}$.

In quasi-static conditions, we can assume that the pressure is uniform throughout the volume $V$ and in all points of its surface $\partial V$, so that we can take $P$ outside the integral

$\dot{W} = - P \displaystyle \oint_{\partial V} \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbf{u}$.

The last step tells you the meaning of the integral. Using Reynolds' transport theorem for the constant function $f(\mathbf{r}) = 1$, we get

$\displaystyle
 \dfrac{d V}{dt} = \dfrac{d}{dt} \int_V 1 \ dV =
 \dfrac{d}{dt} \int_V f(\mathbf{r}) dV = \int_V \underbrace{\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}}_{=0 \text{ since $f(\mathbf{r}) = 1$}} dV + \oint_{\partial V} \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = \oint_{\partial V} \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}}$,

i.e. the integral term above is the time derivative of the volume $V$. Putting everything together, recalling that the power $\dot{W}$ is the time derivative of the work $W$, we get

$\dfrac{d W}{dt} = - P \dfrac{d V}{d t}$,

whose incremental expression reads
$\delta W = - P \delta V$. Minus sign comes since this is the work of forces acting on the system, and not the work done by the system: change sign to get the result you need.

Comment: Yeah, this is the general way using arbitrary moving surfaces. I didn't think the asker was looking for an answer like this, but I did refer him to that branch of math if he wants to see more.

Comment: @Poisson Aerohead actually the very reason I asked this question was to get an insight on something as deep and as rigorous as possibble. And I'm greatful for such responses!

Comment: The Renolds Transport theorem is really a special case comparing a volume fixed in space to a volume that moves precisely with the mass (the so called control volume and control mass). In general, all volumes are possible, the volume can move and deform and the mass can flow through the boundary. In CMS you would get general results which would show Reynolds Transport as a special case. The math is very hard though, as you can imagine "deforming surfaces" is a really big idea. I do recommend the Grinfeld book as a self study, as I've never seen a school use it.

Comment: without any book, that a look at these notes https://basics.altervista.org/test/Math/time_derivatives_of_integrals/time_derivatives_of_integrals.html

Answer (score 10):

$$\delta W=F\delta x=F\frac{\delta V}A=\frac FA\delta V=P\delta V$$

Comment: This is the most straight forward answer to the question as posed.

Comment: The OP asked about the general case. Why would, in general, the work be done along direction $x$? That looks like the usual, limited to the 1D case, proof for a cylinder.

Comment: @Miyase *Why would, in general, the work be done along direction $x$?*" I simply started from the very definition of work: $W=\int F\, \mathrm dx\,.$

Comment: @Steeven That isn't the definition, it's a special case where all small displacements are alongside the same direction x. If the system has a shape (not point-like), pressure forces will act perpendicular to its surface, so there can be different directions on differents points.

Comment: P is thermodynamic pressure, which is -dU/dV. F/A is mechanical pressure. This proof is missing the proof that these two are the same.

Answer (score 4):

IMO the answer by @Steeven is the most direct one. So the purpose of this answer is to support his.

The expression for work can be shown in various forms. The most basic is force times displacement. But force times displacement can take many additional forms.

In thermodynamics, for a closed system, $PdV$ work is what we call "boundary work". It is the work that either expands or contracts the boundary between the system and its surroundings. So instead of a force causing the linear displacement of an object, boundary work is pressure causing an increase or decrease in the volume of the system. Mathematically, that works out to be the same thing, as @Steeven has shown.

Another form of work involves torque times angular displacement. Again, mathematically, it can be shown it is the same thing as force times displacement.

> ***Edit:*** I would also like to remind that $\,\delta W = P dV\,$ holds for *reversible* processes only. So the answer must use this
> assumption

That is not correct. For any process, reversible or irreversible, the pressure $P$ in $PdV$ is always the external pressure. If (and only if) the process is reversible, then $P$ in $PdV$ is also the pressure of the gas which, for a reversible process, is always in equilibrium with the external pressure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I meant that only for reversible processes we can replace $\delta W$ in The First law of Thermodynamics with $P dV$

Comment: The first law does not distinguish between reversible and irreversible work, only the second law does. For irreversible work P is the external pressure only. For reversible work, it is both the external pressure and the equilibrium pressure of the gas. In any case, what does that have to do with your original question. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Sgg8 BTW, the statement "P is the pressure of a gas" should have been in the EDIT paragraph. I completely missed it assuming the entire edit was under EDIT. If I missed it, others probably did too.

Answer (score 3):

Define a volume $V$ under pressure $P$. The total differential work done in a differential process, $\delta W$, is that pressure times the perpendicular movement of the 6 faces of the cube. This will be $dV$. Any valid coordinate transformation will not change that result, it will just change the form of the $dV$ by a Jacobian.

Note that convention matters. This is $\delta W_{out}$, not $\delta W_{in}$. Using work out is customary in thermodynamics for engines and such, so $dE = \delta Q_{in} - \delta W_{out} = \delta Q_{in} - PdV$. If you had said $dE = \delta Q_{in} + \delta W_{in}$, you would still negate the $PdV$ term.

Please note that this problem is a notational nightmare. If you want to study a differential volume, it is natural to call it $dV$, but then, what do you call the change in volume? My initial answer called the volume $dV$, but this then confuses the "other" $dV$, which is the change in the volume. However, you can view it for any finite volume $V$ and imagine that volume going to zero, and that probably is enough precision for you. Otherwise, I will refer you to [the calculus of moving surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_moving_surfaces), which is the proper mathematical formalism for this sort of thing. It is pretty difficult, though. I would recommend a book entitled *Tensor Analysis and the Calculus of Moving Surfaces* by Pavel Grinfeld if you are interested in going deeper. It is one of the best I have seen, and the treatment of tensors is incredibly elegant.

It is worth noting that "the piston" you always see as the example is a very simple application of the calculus of moving surfaces.

Comment: I updated this to provide a reference to some better mathematical formalism.

Comment: Using the more common version of the first law where $dE=\delta Q-\delta W$, $\delta W$ is work out.

Comment: Yes, Bob, I thought about it and updated that portion. Let me know what you think.